# Compound interest in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that takes a given amount (a) and uses a set interest rate of 10% annually to find out how long it would take to accumulate 1,000,000. The problem is that all the examples I can find only show examples for simple interest as below.

```
echo " Enter the principle value: "
read p
echo " Enter the rate of interest:"
read r
echo " Enter the time period:"
read t
s=`expr $p \* $t \* $r / 100`
echo " The simple interest is "
echo $s
```

The problem is I need it for compound interest. I was thinking the answer might be in a while loop with a counter that added up how man times the loop ran with the fixed amount of money and interest until million is hit and then echoed the number of loops. My problem (being math challenged) is I don't know what that formula would look like and I can't find any examples of it on the net in bash.

Comment: You just multiply by 1.1 each time...

Comment: You'll get nowhere with `expr` as it only does **integer arithmetic**. You need `bc` or `dc`, which are calculators. Read their manual pages.

Comment: I just found out that I am supposed to use this total=$(bc<<<"scale=2;$total +  $total * .9")   Still not sure on how to implement it yet. Here is the bc page but still not clicking yet. http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/archive/23/command-line-calculations-using-bc/

Comment: I wanted to fix this for any one else how might find it. the bc should look like this     total=$(bc,,,"scale=2;$total=$total * .1") not .9 as above. Now I just got to do some homework to run it in a loop until I hit a set number and then have the script count the loop and that will tell me how many years it will take to hit that number.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v P=100000 -v i=10 'BEGIN{print log(1000000/P)/log(1+i/100)}'

24.1589
```

starting with principal 100,000, with 10% interest rate, it will take little over 24 years to reach 1M.

Comment: Alright, you get this one, (even though it's tagged `bash`) because the `awk` solution is much more efficient than multiple calls to `bc`, hands down.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `bc` isn't bash either.

Comment: Oh no, and I wasn't suggesting it was... but the only way to get bash to skin that cat is with `bc` or `dc` or multiply everything by some amount to allow the integer math to preserve the significant digits and then pass a final calc to `bc` or move the decimal point manually.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `bc` is as much `bash` as `awk` is, honestly don't know how that is getting bash to skin that cat.

Comment: I see what you are saying, just another utility outside the shell. My point being that generally when someone is trying to incorporate floating point within the framework of a shell script, calls to `bc` are more the norm seen than a separate `awk` script. But, yes, they are both as utilitarian as utilities can be separate and distinct from the shell.

Comment: awk is not a lesson we have yet to come across in class..So I needed it with the bc function but thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You have the right idea for the script -- a loop where you multiply each iteration until you hit the target.   As far as the math goes, it depends on the details of the question.   If you get 10% interest at the end of the year every year (then the interest is not compounded), and the formula for each year is:

```
interest = 10% * total;  
total = total + interest;
```

or, more concisely, `total = 100% * total + 10% * total`, which simplifies to `110% * total`.   Of course 100% is 1, and 110% is 1.1, thus you get:

```
total = 1.1 * total
```

If your interest is compounded monthly, things become more complicated.  In this case, you get `110% ^ (1/12)` interest each month...   so then your loop would go iterate monthly, and you would get:

```
 total = (1.1 ^ (1/12)) * total
```

And the number of iterations would represent the number of months, not years.

Comment: The problem is bash can only handle `integer` math. You can use `bc` or other utilities to handle floating-point, but bash has no native capability.

Comment: Ok, so multiply everything by 10000, do the math with integers, and then divide by 10000....